# Laravel InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, laravel

hi all im having issue with a script i am helping a friend install

```html
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [admin.cms] not found.
in FileViewFinder.php line 137
at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('admin.cms', array('/volume1/web/resources/views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79
at FileViewFinder->find('admin.cms') in Factory.php line 174
at Factory->make('admin.cms', array('data' => ''), array()) in helpers.php line 858
at view('admin.cms', array('data' => '')) in CmsController.php line 70
at CmsController->dashboard()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CmsController), 'dashboard'), array()) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('dashboard', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(CmsController), 'dashboard') in Route.php line 189
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 653
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in RedirectIfNotCms.php line 24
at RedirectIfNotCms->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckLanguage.php line 27
at CheckLanguage->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 43
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure), 'cms') in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 655
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 629
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Debugbar.php line 51
at Debugbar->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

at fileviewfinder.php 137

```html
    protected function findInPaths($name, $paths)
    {
        foreach ((array) $paths as $path) {
            foreach ($this->getPossibleViewFiles($name) as $file) {
                if ($this->files->exists($viewPath = $path.'/'.$file)) {
                    return $viewPath;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new InvalidArgumentException("View [$name] not found.");
    }

    /**
```

Im not sure what issue is i have checked that the paths are correct.

any help or a point in direction would be greatly appreciated

Server is Running Apache 2.4 and php version 7.2   Im not sure what issue is i have checked that the paths are correct.

any help or a point in direction would be greatly appreciated

Server is Running Apache 2.4 and php version 7.2

Comment: `View [admin.cms] not found` . Do you have a view named `admin.cms`?

Comment: Is there something unclear about that error message? It's saying you don't have a view `admin.cms`. Note that paths are `.` separated in the `view()` method, so `admin.cms` would point to `resources/views/admin/cms.blade.php`. Does that file exist? If not; there's your issue.

Comment: nope ive checked both resources and view folder

Comment: Closest i have is \resources\views\admin\cms

contains
create.blade.php
edit.blade.php
index.blade.php

Comment: Then your view would be `admin.cms.index`, `admin.cms.create` or `admin.cms.edit`. If `cms` is a `folder`, then you need to return one of the views within that folder via `cms.{whatever}`

Comment: @KyleSmith check my answer then

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure that your view file is in `resources` folder, and it got `.blade.php` as extension.

you can do this as well `dd(view()->exists($yourview));` it should return `true` if the view exists, false if not.

Start from there and you will get to the solution.